# Uninstalling xubuntu-desktop help login

Tags: unity, xubuntu, login, lightdm

i installed xubuntu-desktop via the code below :

```
Sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

But after installing, a few functions did not work such as the system properties and other stuff in the computer icon on the right corner.
Anyways, i uninstalled it via this code that was posted on the forum some time ago :

```
Sudo apt-get autoremove xubuntu* && apt-get autoremove xfce*
```

The first command removed about 24mb and the second one about 54.5mb.

Now when i restart or logoff, the default login screen that came with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS is not the same as it was before, the login credentials is in the middle of the screen and the cog button that changed the DE went up in the right corner, But when i lock the session it is normal Unity login screen as it was before. What did i do wrong and how to fix this ?

By the way it did not promt me for lightdm or gdm .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. All I had to do is go to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` and find out that Xubuntu changed the ubuntu config file. I changed the name and fixed the line `user-session=xubuntu` to `user-session=ubuntu` and added the line `greeter-session=unity-greeter` and saved it.

Then

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm unity-greeter
```

and restart and voilá.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(xubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(xfce),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but what is the code doing exactly?

Comment: Go to: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/aptitude.8.html. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/deborphan.1.html. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/apt-get.8.html

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu uses lightdm-gtk-greeter as the default greeter, while the default greeter in standard Ubuntu is unity-greeter. All you need to do to get unity-greeter "back" is uninstalling lightdm-gtk-greeter.

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter
```